# await/async odd behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a simple Console Application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MockAPI api = new MockAPI();
            Task t = api.GetVersion();
            var placeBreakPoint = "breakpoint";
        }
    }

    public class MockAPI
    {
        public async Task<string> GetVersion() 
        {
            return await APIVersion();
        }

        private async Task<string> APIVersion()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            return "v1.0";
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this the first time it executed as I expect seeing the code go all the way to

```
await Task.Delay(3000);
```

and then returning to

```
var placeBreakPoint = "breakpoint";
```

before returning to

```
return "v1.0";
```

when the delay had been completed. However running the code thereafter sees the code execute as before but never return from the `Task.Delay`. I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for your task so your application ends before the task has a chance to complete.

You need to `Wait` or `await` it (which you can't do in `Main` but should do anywhere else).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MockAPI api = new MockAPI();
    Task t = api.GetVersion();
    var placeBreakPoint = "breakpoint";
    t.Wait();
}
```

Comment: @user1054637 What do you mean the first time?

Comment: I tested with Wait and that works, so thanks for that. I mean when I first ran the code I ran above I did see a return to the APIVersion method after it had hit the placeBreakPoint line in Main, but only the first time. Subsequent runs it just ended as you described before the task had a chance to complete.

Comment: @user1054637 That could be due to race conditions, but I doubt that happened. Maybe you had a smaller delay, or stopped at a breakpoint.